# How scan picture containing QR code from the album in the device by Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, qr-code, cordova-plugins, scanning

I used https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner to Scan QR code, but I want scan the picture containing QR code in album on my device

I searched but don't have any support

Thanks all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a js library like https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode. In your code, do something like
`qrcode.decode("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData);`

You can test it here: http://www.webqr.com/

It shows two options: one using a live feed, and one using an uploaded image, the one you need.